# A nested net-snmp snmptrap message sending example

Tags: snmp, net-snmp, snmp-trap

Most of the examples provided for sending SNMP traps are simple ones like the one below.

```
snmptrap -v 1 -c public host TRAP-TEST-MIB::demotraps localhost 6 17 '' \
    SNMPv2-MIB::sysLocation.0 s "Just here"
```

Take any MIB file, they contain many complex object groups, for example, systemGroup contains sysLocation, sysName, etc.

Could someone help in bringing out examples to show the way how to send snmp traps which includes such OBJECT-GROUPS. Adding one more question here, Does SNMPTRAPD support internationalization?

Comment: Does not look like a programming question to me. Questions on enterprise IT or network management belong on Serverfault.com.

Comment: @Jqlta The question is all about generating a complex structured SNMP trap and UNICODE support in NET-SNMP open source code.

Comment: Aha, that is indeed a programming question. The example led me to think it was only related to the command line tool.

Comment: The question about Unicode should be posted as a separate question, and perhaps clarified a bit - unicode support is not the same as internationalization.

Comment: Yeah. Please replace it as UTF-8 encoding. @Jolta, do you have any idea to bring in internationalization in NET-SNMP's snmptrapd code?

Comment: I'm saying, you can edit the question yourself, and you should: Remove the "one more question" and post it as a separate question. The rule on StackOverflow is "one question per question".
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts

Answer (score 3):

It is really bad practice to define the SNMP notification (trap or inform) the way that it contains the entire OBJECT GROUP or even worse the entire SNMP table. The reason is that you don't really need all these variables anyway. The other reason is that the packet/PDU is limited by MTU size. So it is possible that you'll not be able to send the data within single UDP packet due to its size.

The proper scenario would be to have few varbinds and you could also initiate some polling cycle to find out what happens if you need more details when you receive such trap.

SNMPTRAPD and NET-SNMP library in general do not support internationalization (UNICODE). The library is limited to ASCII charset only.

There are commercial products on the market including [NetDecision TrapVision](http://www.netmechanica.com/products/?prod_id=1003) and some other that fully support UTF-8 internationalization.

Comment: Thanks for detailing on this. It might be a bad practice to have complex structures in SNMP trap message. But I need to test a SNMP trap listener to see how the system handles such object group or table. So, Could you just give some examples to generate such traps using snmptrap application provided by NET-SNMP.

Comment: You can simply specify all the variables within OBJECT GROUP  in `snmptrap` command to send out the target trap. The SNMPTRAPD does not really care if the trap matches the MIB definition. So it will print the incoming trap as is.

Comment: Do NET SNMP snmptrap send support object group as trap varbind?

Comment: No, it does not. That's why I've proposed the workaround in my previous answer

Comment: As you have said, just by simply specifying all the variables within object group in snmptrap command. Could you please provide an example containing object group in netsnmp snmptrap send syntax which I didn't find anywhere.

Comment: Normally a trap notifying of complex data would only contain an OID which is a row pointer into a table, or similiar, which the Manager can poll to get the complex data.

Comment: An example please.